# What’s the meaning of the rabbit in the talons of an eagle?

Tags: symbols

[Eagle House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eagle_House,_London), in Mitcham, south west London, England, was built around 1706, probably for Fernando Mendez a royal physician.

On top of two brick piers at the front of the house is a statue of an eagle with a rabbit in its talons.

[image: Eagle House statue]

[Fernando Mendez](https://mitchamhistorynotes.com/2020/12/18/fernando-mendez/) was Jewish and lived in Portugal. He converted (‘Marrano’). The chosen name Fernando Mendez was an attempt to fit in, was the eagle and rabbit in the same vein?

Was the eagle and rabbit common in Spain and Portugal at that time?

What does it signify?

Comment: "As Jews had no recognized position in the feudal system after this period, they could not use these devices, though for some time they were ranked with nobles, and had the right of deciding their disputes by duel. Consequently, no Jewish coats of arms were recognized by the heralds in the Middle Ages; though rich Jewish families of means used devices, as is shown by the occurrence of heraldic Seals." _[JewishEncyclopedia](https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/4428-coat-of-arms)_ - Did Mendez convert?  Is there any evidence that the statues _have_ a meaning?

Comment: [Spanish imperial eagle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spanish_imperial_eagle)?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace as a ‘Marrano’ he converted. The chosen name Fernando Mendez was an attempt to fit in, was the eagle and rabbit in the same vein?

Comment: I've moved your comment into the question - please edit for clarity.  I _had been_ working on the assumption that he was Jewish, which meant that the symbols _could not_ be heraldic in nature.  Now that I realize he was potentially armigerous, it opens the possibility of checking both Iberian and English arms.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace thanks for your help.

Comment: I've checked "Iconografía y Simbolismo del arte ibérico" by David de la Garma and eagles with rabbits or hares in their claws were common in Spain and Portugal until the 18th century (the end of the Baroque era) as "a symbol of the power of God over mankind". But this was Christian symbology, not Jewish.

Comment: Dinner, perchance?

Comment: Thank you, @CarlosMartin - as he was a Jew who wanted to appear to be a Christian, then that would fit.

Comment: It seems it was a common motif all around Europe because "British examples can be found in the Cathedrals of Wells, Worcester, Norwich and Ribbesford" and the book cites "ANDERSON, M.D. Animal carvings in British Churches. Cambridge University Press, 1938."

Comment: @CarlosMartin I think that you should include your explanations and references as an answer